# Calculate the number of days this year for a date using Howard Hinnant's date.h

Tags: c++, date, c++17

I am attempting to use this c++ date [library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) to calculate the number of days since the start of the year for a specific date.

I can create the date object:

```
date::year_month_day queryDate((date::year(2019)), date::month(8), date::day(22));
```

I can subtract it from the start of the year...

```
date::year_month_day startOfYear((date::year(2019)), date::month(1), date::day(1));

queryDate - startOfYear
```

However, I am then unable to convert this result into a number of days.

Comment: Be patient, and I wouldn't be surprised if Howard himself will drop by and help answer your question.

Comment: You should not be able to subtract them.

Comment: First question of the FAQ: [Why can't I do day arithmetic on a year_month_day?](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/FAQ#day_arithmetic)

Comment: @T.C. Beat me to it, with the correct answer no less. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert both to `sys_days`, then subtract the result.

```
auto daysSinceStartOfYear = date::sys_days(queryDate) - date::sys_days(startOfYear);
```